# CWM for unsupported device but with same specs

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery

I have an archos 40 titanium and I'd like to install cwm (already rooted). There is no official support but on [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2573743) thread they say their  instructions worked for the [45 titanium](http://www.archos.com/fr/products/smartphones/titanium/archos_45titanium/specs.html?#menu) which has almost the same specifications (same processor and RAM amount ), only the screen size differ (+0.5 inch). Is it considered safe to follow the instructions for my 40ti?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unofficially modifying your phone, nothing is safe... But if others say it worked, give it a shot.  Just keep in mind that anything can go wrong, so back up your data and have a Plan B for recovering your system.

Edit:  Plan B (how to recover your phone):

Recovery Software:  http://www.archos.com/faq/index.php?action=artikel&cat=120&id=301

Stock ROM:  http://update.archos.com/AFMv1/storage//files/full/a40ti/20130922.101129/OTA972121_8916_V007049.zip

Comment: Thank you. What plan B? Backup the recovery mode using fastboot?

Comment: Sure, that'd work. I'd just find fastboot files and get ready to flash them if needed.

Comment: I saw that there is no fastboot backup command, so how?

Comment: I'm on moble so my ability to help is somewhat crippled, my apologies. Google stock ROM (your phone model)

Comment: I just edited my answer with what you will need to recover your phone if it goes fubar

Comment: Thank you very much! One more thing: where is the recovery software? It is only talking of wiping

Comment: That's what you want.  It'll wipe and restore.

Comment: And the recovery  image as well?

Comment: Yes. It'll wipe your phone completely.

Comment: if it work T_T I tried to wipe it using fastboot and system settings, it didn't worked since the flashing wasn't successful. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79363/sim-sd-card-not-detected

Comment: @Vinz243 I'll answer on your new question.