# SIM Card not detected after failed recovery flash

Tags: rom-flashing, sd-card, recovery-mode, sim-card

I recently tried to install CWM on my rooted archos 40 titanium. Unlocking the bootloader using `fastboot oem unlock` doesn't work, I only got ellipses for a while. So I installed Mobiluncle tools and selected [my recovery.img](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2573743) on my sdcard. However after it flashed, it rebooted in recovery, but the recovery doesn't work, it only restart again and again and again.

Fortunately, the device can still start normally, but **now my SD Card isn't detected nor is my SIM card**. I expected it would come from the bad recovery, so I tried to make a `fastboot erase recovery` but the bootloader is locked! I tried a simple Factory Reset in the setting it did nothing, it restarted android without wiping it :(

**How to solve that? Is the fact that I can't read my SD and SIM due to the fact that the recovery doesn't work?**

EDIT:
It seems it's Mobiluncle tools fault since when I closed its process in android settings the SD Card "appears" (but not the SIM card unfortunately)

EDIT 2:

I managed to wipe data partition using a shell, but after reboot the system is very unstable (a lot of apps crashes unfortunately), so I believe it is because I didn't wipe cache. **But now I tried to install Framaroot and root but whatever I try any application that requires root says that my phone isn't rooted. How to root please**

EDIT3:

using adb shell then su:

```
shell@android:/ $ su
su
DIE: file credentials different than expected
1|shell@android:/ $
```

EDIT:

Root now works

EDIT:

I tried, in factory mode, going in individual tests part and then SIM, nothing showed and in Memory Card test it says (`*`means *x* chinese characters)

```
eMMC FAT ***:
******:  (null)
******: **
******: 1266 MB
******: 0 x 4581

SD* 2 :
******: ****
******: 15185 MB
******:  5629 MB
******: 0 x 12675
```

Comment: check is your imei number is there or not, and also check your baseband whether it is showing some figurs or unknown ? if it is unknown then it can be resolved,

Answer (score 1):

Can you access recovery at all?  If so, put [this file](http://update.archos.com/AFMv1/storage//files/full/a40ti/20130922.101129/OTA972121_8916_V007049.zip) on your SD card, and install it using stock recovery.

Comment: Thank you very much but when i reboot to recovery, it just reboot again to android

Comment: Try flashing the Archos provided recovery file in that zip I provided using Mobiluncle

Comment: What if I brick it? I'd like to be able to send it back to Archos after that.

Comment: Well, you're kinda screwed as-is...they'll be able to tell that you modified system files, and therefore, the warranty is void... Your best bet is to do whatever you can on your own to recover it.

Comment: I could lie :) It worked before. I could tell that m smartphone froze sundenly while using StackExchange app for instance and that when I removed the battery everything is buggy. And send it unrooted.

Comment: Or another possiblity is to leave it as is and sell it on ebay at a lower price as a "small tablet". Because it's like a tabet withour the size

Comment: But anyway, is it (the problem that SIM and SD card) because of a bad recovery?

Comment: @Vinz243 I doubt the recovery partition is at fault... But anything is possible.

Comment: Thanks, but what then? I have tow SIM card slot, both don't work and my SIM card works in other phones. :/ A data wipe didn't made anything

Comment: using Mobiluncle to flash using nthe zip it tells me that it will reboot to recovery :(

Comment: @Vinz243 - Honestly, I'm not quite sure where to go from here.  Recovery is pretty much the only hope, other than if your phone has a download mode.  Try holding down VolDwn + Power from an off state, and if that doesn't work, try VolUp + Power.

Comment: Using VolDown + power, I get the factory mode in chinese :(

Comment: That's where you need to be to flash it.

Comment: But unfortunately I can't read chinese. I tried (successfully) 清除e MMC, which made a factory reset - although the SIM Card and the recovery don't work still.

Comment: That 'Chinese mode' should be where you can flash with that flashing tool on your PC that you're using.

Comment: But how please? There is no such option I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16472/discussion-between-iamthesquidward-and-vinz243).