# SIM card undetected after adb reboot recovery

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, sim-card

My SIM and SD cards are not detected by the phone (One Plus X) after I did this command : `adb reboot recovery` and then escape it with a hard reboot (pressing volume UP and lock button)

I tried to restore the phone to factory parameters, but it did not work.

Is there something I did wrong at this point ?

Now I've found a topic similar to mine : [SIM Card not detected after failed recovery flash](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79363/sim-card-not-detected-after-failed-recovery-flash) but it's seems solve by using an undocumented file.

I've tried to root my phone, but could this process solve my case ? [How to unroot the One Plus X](https://theunlockr.com/2016/02/17/how-to-unroot-the-oneplus-x/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sim was the source of the problem. I changed it and my problem was solved.